# Are there any downsides of using satellite view in mapkit?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I wonder if there any downsides of using satellite mode in `MKMapView`?

If it performing as good as the standard map type? Maybe it devours more RAM or downloads more data?

I'm asking because this would be a much better solution in my app to use only satelite view, but I'd like to know if there are any consequences in advance.

As I check it right now, I cannot see any performance decrease comparing to standard mapView type. However, I believe that my use case is pretty basic at the moment and probably some issues I cannot detect this way.

So my questions is about *known* issues with performance using satelite view.

**EDIT**

I played(zoomed, jump all over the world etc) with both satelite and standard map and it turns out that satelite consumes **less** memory than standard one. How come?

Comment: Try it. Test it. Profile it.

Comment: Seems like it would need to download (a lot) more data, as satellite view uses raster image tiles that have to be loaded constantly, at a wide range of different scales. As rmaddy says, do some controlled testing.

Comment: I tried zooming, switching between some continents etc and Network in Xcode keeps showing `Zero KB/s`. Why is that? The entire world cannot be cached by default I guess

Comment: @rmaddy Could you sugesst a reliable way to test it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on doing map tile (256 X 256) captures for offline use, satellite and hybrid map tiles average around 90K Bytes each in rural areas while standard map tiles average about 10K bytes each in those same areas, so there is a major impact on the volume of data downloaded and therefore on the time required.  Note that there is fairly wide variance in the sizes from tile to tile depending on content, though the ratio stays pretty close.